Using Selenium but i get the wrong html page source
I'm attempting to utilize Selenium to retrieve the webpage source of a website and store it in a variable called "html_content." Subsequently, I plan to parse it using BeautifulSoup to extract the necessary data. However, I've encountered an issue: the page source captured by the Selenium Chrome driver differs significantly from what is observed when inspecting the webpage directly. How can this discrepancy be resolved?
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
html_content = driver.page_source
time.sleep(10)
driver.quit()




probably due to updates done via JS after the page load.  Move the sleep to before you get page_source.
